Identity of Moshiach
I heard that Rabbi Avraham Azulai stated that the Moshiach will use his "natural mind" and teach Torah in the language of the world at the time, most probably English.
Not sure if the reference was to his book Chesed leAvraham or Ohr haChama
Can anyone confirm this, and where in that book (chapter or page) does it say that?
Any other major Rabbis say something to this effect?
Thank you.

FWIW I don't think this is in Chesed LeAvraham

What does the title have to do with the question?
